# Change django admin's foreign key widget

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, django-admin, many-to-many

I have a few models in my django project: CoursePacks, Courses and Chapters.

Courses have a many-to-many relationship to the CoursePacks, which in the admin, after some inline editing, displays this widget:

(This is a COURSE-COURSEPACK relationship)

[image: COURSE PACK ADMIN COURSES RELATIONSHIP]

Which allows me to select, edit and create another course which will be automatically added to the course pack.

The chapter ("capítulo") and the course models, however, are connected through a foreign key relationship, and the widget displayed on the admin is the following:

(This is A CHAPTER-COURSE relationship)

[image: COURSE ADMIN CHAPTERS RELATIONSHIP]

Which I have edited so that less fields are shown, because if I didn't all the fields and the entire textarea content would be displayed.

When I click on the add or edit button to the side of the course instance on the course pack admin window, a window pops up which allows me to edit or create another course.

I would like to be able to have a similar mechanism but for creating chapters through the course admin window. Will I have to edit the admin's markup or is there a widget editing functionality that does what I need?

If not, where could I begin to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I ended up finding the answer for this question a little while later. I forgot to post it here, but now I was reminded because I just got a "tumbleweed badge" for this question.

```
class ChapterInline(admin.StackedInline):
model = Chapter
view_on_site = False
exclude = (
    'slug', 'text',

)
show_change_link = True
```

The solution for this issue was merely this `show_change_like = True` piece of code. As for the rest of the code above, it is useful as in it makes the appearance of the inline (below) cleaner.

The `view_on_site` configuration is set to `False` simply because the "View on site" link was not working and I didn't think fixing it was worth the stress, for design reasons.

```
@admin.register(Course)
class CourseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        ChapterInline,
    ]
    #...
```

Which has also had its non-related code taken out, for relevance reasons.

This is the result:
[image]

Which is not really perfect, but it does the job. The only issue is that first a chapter has to be created before it can be edited.